# From the last slide to the first slide with slideUp/slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made my slider but it's acting wierd when it reach the last slide and have to start again on the first. Until getting to the last slide it slides **upwards**, but when it has to go to the first it does it **downwards**. And it kind a misses the first one. I mean - it shows it (even downwards), but on my pagination dots it doestn't add class .selected to the first one. After that it acts normally again until the next cycle.

Why is that two things happening. I've tried to change the `if(active_slide.index() == last_slide.index())` with `if(active_slide.next().length == 0)` /and `<` /; `if(active_slide.is(last_slide))` ... it didn;t help.

Here is jsfiddle http://jsbin.com/iwiroq/4/edit.

Comment: can you put this on jsfiddle?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work .. I will try again

Comment: I've done it: http://jsbin.com/iwiroq/1/edit

Comment: My jsfiddle is not loading ... I would exted the code but .. it's written errror 502 bad gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @yabol's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14519617/1741542), I've built a minimal example with a rolling image list

HTML:

```
<div class="image-slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var image_list = $('.image-slider li');
image_list.hide();
var first_child = '.image-slider li:first-child';
var last_slide = $('.image-slider li:last-child');
var last_index = last_slide.index();
var active_slide = $(first_child);
active_slide.show();
setInterval(next, 5000);

function next(){
    active_slide.slideUp();
    if (active_slide.index() >= last_index)
        $(first_child).insertAfter(active_slide);

    active_slide = active_slide.next();
    active_slide.slideDown();
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LNJD/) or [Tinker](https://tinker.io/e3377) for playing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it slides downwards instead of upwards is because first element of the list is higher in dom tree than the last one. You can work it around by adding first element also as the last one, and the last one element gets loaded you swap it with first.

Comment: I don't get that well. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to clone your first slide into last position, use it to run animation, and then swap `active` slide from your last cloned slide to your first slide.